# Custom View is not loading

Tags: android

I am new to android app development , trying to learn custom view development . Below is the simple layout where i have created a button , click of which will launch Game activity .Game activity has custom layout . 
My issue is , on click of the button , it starts new activity but it do not shows up anything . It loads with empty layout .I am expecting android to load a circle on click of button.

***MainActivity.java***

```
package com.shashi.customview2;


import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View gamebutton=(View) findViewById(R.id.hi);
    gamebutton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    Intent intent =new Intent(this,Game.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

***game.java***

```
package com.shashi.customview2;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class Game extends Activity 
{

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.custlayout);

}

}
```

***Custom View class:***

```
package com.shashi.customview2;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.res.TypedArray;

import android.graphics.Canvas;

import android.graphics.Paint;

import android.graphics.Paint.Style;

import android.util.AttributeSet;

import android.view.View;

public class custview extends View 
{

    private int circleCol;
    private Paint circlePaint;



    public custview(Context context ,AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context,attrs);
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.custview, 0, 0);
        try {
            //get the text and colors specified using the names in attrs.xml
             circleCol = a.getInteger(R.styleable.custview_circleColor, 0);
              } 
        finally 
        {
            a.recycle();
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

protected void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
{

int viewWidthHalf = this.getMeasuredWidth()/2;
int viewHeightHalf = this.getMeasuredHeight()/2;
int radius = 0;

if(viewWidthHalf>viewHeightHalf)

    radius=viewHeightHalf-10;

else
    radius=viewWidthHalf-10;


circlePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

circlePaint.setColor(circleCol);

canvas.drawCircle(viewWidthHalf, viewHeightHalf, radius, circlePaint);

}
```

}

***custom Layout:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.shashi.customview2"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.shashi.customview2.custview
    android:id="@+id/custView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    custom:circleColor="#ff0099"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your Game class too?

Comment: Hi , I have already shared game class. If you scroll down ...you will see game.java. "***custom Layout:***" is "custlayout" called from game class as "setContentView(R.layout.custlayout)"

Comment: Hi, I further tried to analyze using eclipse debug mode by applying  break points at the constructor custview() of the customeView2 class followed by another break point at onDraw(). When we ran the code in debug mode , we observed that once execution point reaches to the constructor custview() and executes codes inside the constructor , then it goes to hang state. It never reaches to onDraw() breakpoint.

Comment: Also, you can try logging. Add `Log.e("TEST","TEST");` to your `onDraw()` method to see if it is printed on your Logcat.  http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Comment: I tried adding Log steps to onDraw() but it did not reach to ondraw() method. Could you please help me understand different steps android executes between constructor call and onDraw() method call. With this infomration , i will try to debug further.

Comment: Make sure that the Game Activity is added to your androidManifest.xml file.